# "When my children are still kids" or "When my children are still young"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

What are the proper/good words would I say to refer to when my children are still kids? Context: my children are now adults, how do I say when I recall back when they are younger, when they are still kids?

Comment: When they ***were*** …

Comment: *When my children were kids/younger*, perhaps?

Comment: _Kids_ is a slang term for _children_ (in the 'young people' sense). As you are talking about your adult children, you could say "When my children were young/younger/small" or (depending on what family you have) "When the boys/girls/Jane and John were kids/children".

Comment: Turning it around: "Before my children grew up, ..."

Comment: Or, "*When my children were **small***", or be more specific about their age, like, "*When my children were **in diapers/still toddlers/not yet interested in dating/...***"

Answer (score 1):

Using "When my children were young" would be accurate in your case I believe. I might be wrong, but pretty sure about the use of 'were'.
The word 'Children' is the plural of 'child'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).